# example 1.4 chapter 1 from mining of massive data sets book

Tags: data-analysis, data-mining

I am reading the book mining of massive data sets. (http://mmds.org/)
In its chapter 1
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch1.pdf
following section is there on page 9.

> Example 1.4: Suppose hash-keys are positive integers. A common and
>   simple hash function is to pick h(x) = x mod B, that is, the remainder
>   when x is divided by B. That choice works ﬁne if our population of
>   hash-keys is all positive integers. 1/Bth of the integers will be
>   assigned to each of the buckets. However, suppose our population is
>   the even integers, and B = 10. Then only buckets 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8 can
>   be the value of h(x), and the hash function is distinctly nonrandom in
>   its behavior. On the other hand, if we picked B = 11, then we would
>   ﬁnd that 1/11th of the even integers get sent to each of the 11
>   buckets, so the hash function would work very well.

I could not understand this statement

hen only buckets 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8 can

> be the value of h(x), and the hash function is distinctly nonrandom in
>   its behavior.

What is the example in this trying to say?
 The hash in my understanding is made by h(x)= x mod B , so if B=10 then x mod 10 will have all values from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sentence a few lines above the particular example

> To be precise, if hash-keys are drawn randomly from a reasonable population of possible hash-keys, then h will send approximately equal numbers of hash-keys to each of the $B$ buckets.

This property is not satisfied, in particular, odd-numbered bins would not have any entry if $B=10$.

However, if $B$ is $11$, then we have $h(2)=2, h(4)=4, h(6)=6, h(8)=8, h(10)=10, h(12)=1$ and so on. Note that even the odd-bins would be filled uniformly. This phenomenon is due to $2$ and $11$ are coprime.

Comment: I am not able to understand your explanation can you elaborate a little bit more.Why will odd number bins not have an entry if B=10. When B=11 then h(2)=2 and so that you mentioned how do you come to that conclusion? The hash in my understanding is made by h(x)= x mod B , so if B=10 then x mod 10 will have all values from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Comment: all the inputs are even numbers. If you write an even number, $d$ as $d=10q+r$. Since $d$ is even and $10q$ is even, $r$ has to be even too. If you write $d=11q+w$, The parity of $11q$ can be odd or even, hence this makes a difference.

Comment: Ok this comment makes some sense, now the line in your answer odd numbered bins would not have any entry if B=10 I am not able to get this line. Then you say B is 11 then we have h(2)=2 can you give an example of how this is possible. I am not able to visualize it. Say x=13 h(x)=13 mod 11 =2 is this what you mean to say, and similarly if x=14 ,h(x)=14 mod 11=3, if x=15 h(x)=15 mod 11 =4 is this what you are trying to say or the example or I have missed something.

Comment: Take an even number, divide it by $10$, will you get an odd remainder? $2$ divided by $11$ will give $2$ as the remainder. As for your example of $x=13$, please remember that your inputs are all even number, you won't get $x=13$ as your input. Similarly, you won't get $x=15$. Try to work out the possible outputs for a few more even numbers and observe that you can hit every bin when $B=11$. (remark: dozing off soon, might not response quickly)

Comment: I re read the question and got it my brain has stopped working when I read things forward, the things or paragraph read  5 minutes ago I forget so I could not connect what I read. I had forgotten that there won't be any odd input as per example.